# Как добавить 2 таблицы: одну с границыми, другую - без? В чем я ошибся?

Tags: html, css, table

Вот страничка https://unbrokenteam.ru/pages/legal-services.html

Нужно, чтобы разноцветная таблица была с границами, а нижняя (где можно оставить телефон и фото), чтобы была без границ.

Повесил разные классы на 2 эти таблицы. У нижней нет границ, но почему-то у верхней их тоже нет. Хотя по идее должны быть серые границы. В классе это прописано.

Вроде все проставил. Не выходит. В чем я ошибся?

[style.css](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/bMwb/Eq44NdxbY)
[legal-services.html](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/oVVK/3mAKXLzsz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу, вот так

Смотрите, берем страницу unbrokenteam.ru таблица в самом низу, table class="table.noBorder"> ..... Не так нужно прописывать класс. Если нужны границы table class="table Border"> Если НЕ НУЖНЫ границы table class="table noBorder">

Comment: Внес изменения. Код выше в основном сообщении. Так же и осталось. На главной странице внизу таблица (там где форма для отправки контактов) осталась с границами.

Comment: посмотрел сайт https://unbrokenteam.ru, там нет данных стилей

Comment: Только что перезалил на хостинг. Должны быть. Сайт надо вбивать именно с https://

Comment: Перешел на сайт, стилей не увидел. Добавил скрины в свой ответ, посмотрите, и обратите внимание на какой строке находится стиль

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня на сайте 2 типа таблицы: с серыми границами https://unbrokenteam.ru/pages/legal-services.html и без https://unbrokenteam.ru/
Но сейчас все с серыми границами. Нужно, чтобы одна таблица была с серыми границами, а другая - нет.

Comment: Каждой таблице даете свой класс и уже в CSS каждому классу приписываете цвет границы

Comment: Так и сделал. Файлы в этой теме и на хостинге обновил. На одной таблице повесил класс с границами, на другой - без. Но почему-то у 2х таблиц нет границ.

Comment: Смотрите, берем страницу https://unbrokenteam.ru
таблица в самом низу, table class="table.noBorder"> .....
Не так нужно прописывать класс. 
Если нужны границы table class="table Border">
Если НЕ НУЖНЫ границы table class="table noBorder">

Comment: То же самое и для тега <td class="table.noBorder.td">....
Если нужны границы <td class="table Border">
Если НЕ НУЖНЫ границы <td class="table noBorder">

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ пожалуйста как верный

Comment: Ок. Все, отметил

Comment: Спасибо, удачи!